# Solar Cell functioning

Tags: voltage, solar-cell, solid-state-devices

I am confused about the operation of solar cell. Maybe its because i still did not quite understand the effect about the voltage drop across a solid state device. We operate in quadrant 4 where current is negative while the voltage is positive and hence they point in the same direction so acting like a battery.I understand how current is being generated because of optical generation but i dont quite understand the voltage being generated by the solar cell. Please give an intuitive answer.
-Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Setence like that:

"I understand how current is being generated because of optical generation but i dont quite understand the voltage being generated by the solar cell"

mean total misunderstanding how the PN junction and solar cell works.

But here is very intuitive description (read all pages):

http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/solar-cell1.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think you didnt understand my question, operation for a solar cell is done in quadrant 4 where the current due to optical generation that basically contributes to drift current  is predominant than that of diffusion. The thing that is confusing me is photovoltaic effect.